# How Does Linking a Node to the End of a Linked List Work?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

What I'm trouble with is not the code, but visualizing this of how its doing its job. I know that first, you have your list (Let's say a list of three elements) and `head` is pointing to the first element, right? Then you'd have your other pointer, say `temp`, and its `temp->next = head`, so far I get it, but this is where I start to lose it... you'd have it traverse through the list until it reaches an element with a `next` variable equal to `NULL`, and then you'd have `temp->next = new_node`!! Like how does this work? All I see it doing is making the pointer point to `new_node` and not making a link to the actual list!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here are your 3 elements ...

`-----      -----      -----
 | 1  | --->| 2  | --->| 3  |--->NULL
 ------     ------     ------`

Arrows in above signify next pointers.

The `head` points to element 1. And also you start with `temp` from element 1. You run a loop and keep doing `temp = temp->next` until `temp->next` is NULL. This way the `temp` keeps traversing right from element 1 to element 3.

The loop breaks when `temp->next` is NULL, that is when the temp is pointing to element 3.

Now at this moment when you do `temp->next = new_node`, element 3's `next` pointer starts to point new_node (the `next` pointer of element 3 is no more `NULL`) .This new_node becomes element 4.